# Apache mod_rewrite and hide source file simultaneously

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have a local `.htaccess` file on a shared hosting service that contains an individual rewrite rule to map `/services` to the file `services.html` within the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^services$ services.html [L]
```

How can I prevent consumers accessing `/services.html` directly (if they sniffed around for it) and have them receive a 404 HTTP response instead?  I do *not* want any consumer knowing I have a `services.html` file at all, and that includes sending 302 responses that would tie back to the original `/services` resource.

However, I tried setting up a rule to return a 404 for `/services.html` but this resulted in `/services` also returning the 404 too.

In summary, I want consumers to only be able to see `/services` endpoint (200 OK) and never know what is mapped behind it, or bypass the publicly chosen endpoint (`services.html` return 404 Not Found).

Comment: If you downvoted, do you mind to share the reason? As far as I understood your question, you want to call /services and get the services.html from DocumentRoot but don't want the URL/URI to change...[P] does that.

Comment: @HelloFishy The down vote was not from me.

Answer (score 0):

Just 'hide' your services.html in the first place and use [P]-parameter for proxying the request.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/services$ http://yourdomain.com/<path-to-the-file>/services.html [P,L]
```

That takes a request like http://yourdomain.com/services and returns http://yourdomain.com//services.html without showing the user where it came from, the browser will still show /services